# Is there an equivalent to Heroku for the ASP.NET platform?

Tags: asp.net, heroku, cloud-hosting, paas

I can't see a reason why we couldn't do the same thing Heroku does for an ASP.NET website.

Anyone care to object?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We're trying to be just that. Go to [appharbor.com](https://appharbor.com) and sign up for an invite and we'll be in touch soon

*more about AppHarbor:*

> [Real alternatives to Windows Azure PaaS (web role)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244038/real-alternatives-to-windows-azure-paas-web-role/7245874#7245874)

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at [www.gearhost.com](http://www.gearhost.com). It's very similar to Heroku in terms of it's offering but for .NET and PHP developers. You get 100 free sites and 100 free databases, just like Heroku.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Moncai](http://moncai.com/)

Comment: I think you mistyped the name of the product. It's **Moncaí**. :-)

Comment: Looks like exactly what I'm after. Hope they launch soon! I'd pay for it to be honest.

Comment: Recent Herding code about Moncai: http://herdingcode.com/?p=294

Comment: It is offline right now

Comment: @AkiraYamamoto prefix with `www` but I'm not sure this is still happening. It shouldn't still be in beta if it was going to launch

Answer (score 3):

maybe http://www.brinkster.com

discussion

https://serverfault.com/questions/139185/is-there-anything-like-heroku-for-php-and-or-net

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766176/anything-like-heroku-for-php-or-net