# Real alternatives to Windows Azure PaaS (web role)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, nosql, cloud-hosting

I am looking for alternatives to the Windows Azure PaaS (Platform as a Service) offering, meeting the following requirements:

1. The platform should provide high availability and scalability.
2. The platform should **manage/update** the application server and OS for me.
3. The platform should provide some form of **NoSQL database** (like Azure Table Storage or SimpleDB).
4. The platform should natively support **ASP.NET MVC**, i.e. IIS & runtime environment should be automatically managed/patched for me.

While Amazon satisfies item 1 and 3, it provides only IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service), meaning that I still have a large administration overhead.

So that question is, what alternatives are there to Windows Azure, that provide a roughly equivalent feature set? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Windows Azure Web Sites does all that. You don't need a cloud service (Web Role). If you're doing MVC, MVC 4 + .Net 4.5 provides many advantages (async for one)

Comment: this should be incorporated into the wiki

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Have you tried [**AppHarbor**](http://AppHarbor.com)?

It's just amazing!

- Runs on top of Amazon EC2
- The entire platform, including application servers, is managed and updated by AppHarbor.
- Applications run inside IIS on fully updated Windows Server 2008 R2 instances.
- .NET 2.0-4.0 is natively supported along with ASP.NET MVC 1, 2 and 3, ASP.NET WebPages, WCF services. Updates are installed as they are released.
- Scaling is [really easy](http://blog.appharbor.com/2011/08/29/application-scaling-now-in-beta) and it takes seconds to deploy. Scaling to multiple instances increases availability and redundancy.
- All website administration including rollback to a previous version and [environment configuration](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments) can be handled through the appharbor.com web interface.
- Builds and tests .NET projects right out of GIT Repository (or Mercurial through [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)).
- MySQL and MSSQL are available as shared and dedicated offerings and optional redundancy for high availability.
- NoSQL databases are supported through [add-ons](http://appharbor.com/addon). Add-ons are also available for e-mail, indexing, caching and performance testing.
- You can use AWS SimpleDB and any other AWS service through your own AWS account. Servers are currently located in US-EAST (Virginia), so put your services there if possible for lower latency.
- [Excellent support](http://support.appharbor.com/)
- [Create background jobs easily](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/900-background-jobs)

This is **Heroku for .NET** :o)

Comment: AppHarbor looks interesting. Where can I find detailed information about performance, costs, SLAs, etc.?

Comment: as I said, it's Amazon EC2 and it's currently Free.

Comment: Thanks Rune, always a privilege to have someone from AppHarbor itself around :)

Comment: As a side note, I have MVC4 running on .Net 4.0 on Appharbor.

Comment: I use AppHarbor 1 years. It quite easy to deploy by GIT compare to Heroku.